AWS CDK: upload notebook to Glue Job
Objective
I want to upload a notebook to AWS Glue using CDK.
Current status
I can export the notebook to a script using nbconvert, upload the script to s3, and then reference the ARN in aws_glue.CfnJob. This works well.
Where I struggle
I still want a notebook I can run cell by cell in AWS Glue.
What I tried

I can upload the notebook to s3 and reference it in aws_glue.CfnJob, but this does not work. I obtain a script in Glue job that is the .ipynb format (more or less JSON from my understanding), as if it would be a python script (so it is not possible to run it).
I can upload the notebook to s3, and try to create a Glue job from it. Hopefully, I can retain the same ARN for the notebook when I upload new versions, and the Glue job will pick up new changes. Unfortunately, it seems not possible to start a Job from a notebook in s3


how are you creating the glue job? have you try specifying job_mode argument?
